# best practice in python multiple comparisons

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

When comparing multiple conditions with 'AND', will the comparisons stop if the first condition is not met?

for example;
    if 'A' AND 'B':
if not 'A', will 'B' be considered?

To remove the negative points for duplication...
If one knew that the problem was called short-circuiting, it could have easily been searched, but the first condition was False in this case and short-circuited the second condition, the search. 
This was a question of which term to search and not on of how the term functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This concept is called [short circuiting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).

This is easily seen in code.

```
def false():
    print('false')
    return False

def true():
    print('true')
    return True

print('false() and true()')
if false() and true():
    pass

# true is not printed

print('true() and false()')
if true() and false():
    pass

# both functions execute
```